# Faking a data member that is created in the constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following class:

```
public class ExampleClass 
{
    private readonly Service service; 

    public ExampleClass()
    {
        service = new Service();
    }

    private void ExecuteProcess()
    {
        var request = Transfer.RequestParameters;
        service.SyncMethod(request);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fake the `private readonly Service` service, that is created in the constructor, because I want to ignore the call to `service.SyncMethod(request)`.
Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Typemock's Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) for faking the Service instance and for invoking the private method,for example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    Service faked = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<Service>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes, ConstructorWillBe.Called);
    ExampleClass exClass = new ExampleClass();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => faked.SyncMethod(null)).IgnoreCall();

    Isolate.Invoke.Method(exClass, "ExecuteProcess");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide a parameterized constructor as follows:

```
public ExampleClass(Service obj)
{
    service = obj;
}
```

Then you could mock and pass the service object to the above constructor & test the function.

It is also recommended to code against an interface, in your case, create an IService, implement it in Service. Then you could inject the interface into the ExampleClass instead of the concrete implementation.

Comment: Or better yet, use an interface (IService), as you should be using interfaces and DI.

Comment: OP want to ignore the call to service.SyncMethod(request) from existing object

Comment: You guys were seconds ahead of me ... +1 to you both

Comment: @Neil: You commented while I had been editing my answer! :) @ Ali: OP has also called out to fake the readonly service

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use something called 'Dependency injection'. This can be done quite easily with for example Ninject or Unity.

The result is that you do not create the service in ExampleClass, but instead pass an object of type IService to the constructor.

The interface has a method SyncMethod.

You let Service implement interface IService. You create a TestService or something that also implements IService.

In your TestService object you can make an empty implementation of the method SyncMethod to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Your class in its current state is too tightly coupled to the dependent service, making it difficult (*but not impossible*) to mock dependencies to be able to test the class in isolation.

First classes should depend on abstractions and not on concretions. So abstract the `Service` behind an interface to allow for it to be more flexible when maintaining and testing your code in isolation.

For example

```
public interface IService {
    void SyncMethod(RequestParameters request);
}

public class Service : IService {
    //..code removed for brevity
}
```

Then refactor your class to follow the [Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/). This approach is known as "constructor injection".

```
public class ExampleClass {
    private readonly IService service;

    public ExampleClass(IService servic) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    private void ExecuteProcess() {
        var request = Transfer.RequestParameters;
        service.SyncMethod(request);
    }
}
```

In production, the actual dependency will be registered with the dependency container in the composition root and when the class is being resolved, the dependencies will be realized and injected into the dependent class.

This also allows for mocks/fakes/stubs to be used during testing either manually or with a mocking framework/tool of your choice.